# WPF Binding with StringFormat

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

Could anyone explain to me why this does not render "VALUE IS DEFAULT"?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Fail, StringFormat=VALUE IS {0}, FallbackValue=DEFAULT}" />
```

There is something tricky about this syntax I am missing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binding in WPF does not consider *StringFormat* while falling back to *FallbackValue* in case it fails.

You can use what **leon** suggested or go with *PriorityBinding*.

--EDIT--

This should work:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Fail, FallbackValue=DEFAULT}" Text="{Binding StringFormat=VALUE IS {0}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it could also work using the runs inside the TextBlock :

```
     <TextBlock>
             <Run Text="Value is : "/>
             <Run Text="{Binding Fail,FallbackValue=Default}"/>
     </TextBlock>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The default fallback value is used for priority bindings, if you'd like to display "VALUE IS DEFAULT" for a fallback value, try the following.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Fail, StringFormat=VALUE IS {0}, FallbackValue='VALUE IS DEFAULT'}" />
```

Comment: Do you mean if the FallbackBinding is used the StringFormat is not?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that StringFormat is ignored when FallbackValue